# JDBC and JDBI: @QueryTimeOut not applying with Redshift database

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-redshift, jdbi

I'm using JDBI with the Redshift database. The driver seems to be completely ignoring the QueryTimeOut annotation that JDBI provides, which leads me to think that the Redshift driver doesn't support it, perhaps?

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT MAX(mydate) FROM mytable ")
@QueryTimeOut(60)
protected abstract String getMyDate();
```

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Stuck here too :(